# Finding pixel position after imrotate (matlab)

Tags: matlab, math, geometry

### Hello

### I have a problem of finding pixel position after imrotate

```
`img = imread('rice.png');
point = [100;120];
angle = 45;
img_rot = imrotate(img,angle);
new_point ??`
```

Comment: Please tell us what, specifically, is the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I want to find point position after image rotation .. for exemple i rotate face image i know the position of eyes before the rotation ... but i want to find the new position of eyes after the rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way: Apply the same transformation to a image with a single dot:

```
s=size(img);
marker=zeros(s(1:2));
marker(point(1),point(2))=1;
marker_rot = imrotate(marker,angle);
[x,y]=find(marker_rot)
```

Comment: Please tell me this uses sparse matrices ;)

Comment: No it does not. Especially when applying this to multiple points, there is a better solution.